# Why does percentage format specifier multiply by 100?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Why does the 'p' string format for percent multiply the value by 100 before formatting it with the percentage sign?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString

> **The Percent ("P") Format Specifier**
>
> ***The percent ("P") format specifier multiplies a number by 100 and
>   converts it to a string that represents a percentage.*** The precision
>   specifier indicates the desired number of decimal places. If the
>   precision specifier is omitted, the default numeric precision supplied
>   by the current PercentDecimalDigits property is used.

Is there any way to prevent the value from being multiplied by 100 before formatting? Rather than doing:

```
(value / 100).ToString("p")
```

Comment: Usually you work with decimal percents inside of code (like `0.5` -> `50%`). The user likes to see nice whole-ish numbers with a percent sign, which is what this function does.

Comment: Maybe because a number like "1% of something" actually means "something / 100.0"?

Comment: @Blender: Not usually, always!

Comment: Percent => Per Cent (per centum meaning “per hundred” in Latin), source wiki, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage

Comment: @Akash - That's awesome, learn something new every-day. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As to the *why*, "percent" literally means "out of one hundred", so 50% is mathematically equivalent to `0.50`. As to formatting, why not just add a percent sign?

```
value + "%"
```

... or something like this:

```
value.ToString("#.00\\%")
```

Comment: Percentage sign usage is culture specific, some cultures put it at the start, some at the end, some specify 50.00% rather than 50%, etc. So want to format to percentage.

Comment: @Phill: What exactly is driving your requirements? For example, why don't you want to divide the number by 100 before formatting? Is this just some arbitrary requirement you came up with, or is there some reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Phill For education's sake, to overcome this, you could use `CurrentUICulture.NumberFormatInfo`, and use this info to create your own culturally-correct formatting (as `ToString` does, without the division).  Boy, doesn't that sound like fun?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - No requirement, just we have to format numbers/currency on the users culture, I figured it would be nice to have percentage formatted to the users culture also, but having already worked out that the percentage is 25(%), I just want it to put the '%' in the correct position based on the culture. Can divide by 100 first, just seems like a hack, thought there might be a way to avoid the multiplying.

Comment: @Phill: I think dividing by 100 is the least hacky approach, unless you want to go to the source where you're calculating your percentage and prevent it from multiplying by 100 in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You normally work with decimal percents inside of code, like `0.5` and `1.0`, but the user likes to see nice whole numbers with a percent sign tacked on the end.

Percent means *"out of `100`"* and clearly your decimal percents are out of `1`. Therefore,  `.ToString("p")` multiplies your number by `100` and then appends a percent sign.

It's just the definition.

Comment: What does "your function" refer to in your answer?

Comment: @Gabe: I'll be a little more verbose, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to multiply the value by 100 , just want the percentage % besides the value entered , i.e. VALUE.00 % if value entered otherwise default 0.00%, then the answer is

PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = "#0.00\%";

It definitely worked for me !!

Comment: The question was **why** does this behavior occur, and not how to format it correctly

Comment: This may not have answered the question, but I found it valueable, so +1 from me